# How to set Text Clock or Text View On Live Wallpaper ? is it possible to set hole xml loyout on wallpaper?

Tags: android, textview, wallpaper, live-wallpaper, android-wallpaper

I want to develop digital clock I have complete the whole layout in XML. But Now I Want to Set it on Wallpaper. Is there any way to set Text Clock On wallpaper.